# How to do Angular typed forms with code generation

Tags: javascript, angular, forms, ecmascript-6, openapi

I'm big fan of schemas and generated code to keep everything synchronized and catch typing errors at compile time.

Angular reactive forms seems to rely on magic string keys to access the form state out of the box.

I would like to generate data models from OpenAPI schema and make the form access logic to adhere to schema with strong typing.

What is the best way to achieve strongly typed forms in angular?

Comment: For generating data models from openapi i would recommend `NSwag` - https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag

Answer (score 0):

Why not use https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-forms-type?

This library has also been officially recommended at the ng-conf 2021: https://youtu.be/Ns8HrYLHzxo?t=3158

Comment: because its a 404 :P